# StringIO with binary files?

Tags: python, string, file, stringio

I seem to get different outputs:

```
from StringIO import *

file = open('1.bmp', 'r')

print file.read(), '\n'
print StringIO(file.read()).getvalue()
```

Why? Is it because StringIO only supports text strings or something?

Comment: with that code, the second file.read() would get nothing. You should use seek(0) before reading the file again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call `file.read()`, it will read the entire file into memory. Then, if you call `file.read()` again on the same file object, it will already have reached the end of the file, so it will only return an empty string.

Instead, try e.g. reopening the file:

```
from StringIO import *

file = open('1.bmp', 'r')
print file.read(), '\n'
file.close()

file2 = open('1.bmp', 'r')
print StringIO(file2.read()).getvalue()
file2.close()
```

You can also use the `with` statement to make that code cleaner:

```
from StringIO import *

with open('1.bmp', 'r') as file:
    print file.read(), '\n'

with open('1.bmp', 'r') as file2:
    print StringIO(file2.read()).getvalue()
```

As an aside, I would recommend opening binary files in binary mode: `open('1.bmp', 'rb')`

Comment: Yes, you're right. That didn't completely solve my real world problem, then I figured out I was writing the data in 'w' mode and getting corrupt files, not 'wb'. Now everything works :)

Comment: I think that file.seek(0), proposed by minhee, is a much better approach.

Answer (score 5):

The second `file.read()` actually returns just an empty string. You should do `file.seek(0)` to rewind the internal file offset.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't you be using `"rb"` to open, instead of just `"r"`, since this mode assumes that you'll be processing only ASCII characters and EOFs?

Comment: On some platforms (and everywhere on Python 3) just `r` means binary mode. Also, please also don't add taglines / signatures to your posts.